# Prevent Phone Screen Popping Up

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have an app I'm working on that when  a button is pressed will call a number on the iPhone. That said, I want to prevent the phone screen from popping up and instead keep the app open as is. Here's my code so far. I have no idea if this is even possible. Any help would be great.

```
NSString *phNo = @"+919876543210";
NSURL *phoneUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"telprompt:%@",phNo]];

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:phoneUrl]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:phoneUrl];
    } else
    {
        calert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Call facility is not available!!!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [calert show];
    }
```

Comment: You want the call to happen in the background while your app is running on the top?

Comment: Correct. They make the call but the app is still running on their screen.

Comment: You'll need to use your own VoIP framework. The way your doing it, it is not possible

Comment: Using `openURL:` always opens the other app moving yours to the background.

Comment: Hmm so something like `Twilio` would be the only way to go. It would be nice if I didn't have to pay for a service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All calls made through traditional phone numbers can only use the iPhone's phone app.

As has been suggested, if you create your own VOIP service or use an existing one, you'll be able to process this call in-app as a data call.